# Yahoo Finance Headlines webpage scraping with R

Tags: html, r, web, web-scraping

I would like to use R to download the HTML code of any Yahoo Finance Headlines webpage,  select the "headlines" and collect them in Excel. Unfortunately  I cannot find and select the HTML nodes corresponding to the headlines once I download  the source file to R.

Let me show the problem with an example.
I started with

```
source <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=AAPL+Headlines"
file <- "destination/finance_file.cvs"
download.file(url = source, destfile = file)
 x = scan(file, what = "", sep = "\n")
```

producing the Excel file `finance_file.cvs` and, most importantly, the character `x`.

Using `x` I would like to collect the headlines and write them into a column in a second Excel file, called `headlines.cvs`.

My problem now is the following: if I select any headline I can find it in the HTML code of the webpage itself, but I lose its track in `x`. Therefore, I do not know how to extract it.

For the extraction I was thinking of

```
x = x[grep("some string of characters to do the job", x)]
```

but I am no expert in web scraping.
Any ideas/suggestions?

I thank you very much!

Comment: Your URL is incorrect: you probably want `http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=AAPL+Headlines`, with `h` (headlines) instead of `ks` (key statistics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `XML` package and write the XPath query needed to extract the headlines.

Since the web page looks like:

```
...
<ul class="newsheadlines"/>
<ul>
  <li><a href="...">First headline</a></li>
  ...
```

you get the following query.

```
library(XML)
source <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=AAPL+Headlines"
d <- htmlParse(source)
xpathSApply(d, "//ul[contains(@class,'newsheadlines')]/following::ul/li/a", xmlValue)
free(d)
```